# Dúvida Erro Árvore em Haskell

Tags: programação-funcional, haskell

Meu professor, em uma questão de haskell pediu para definir árvore da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo que definindo dessa maneira dá esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E em muitos cantos da internet, a árvore em haskell eles definem usando Data como a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então gostaria de saber, se o professor está correto em declarar arvore esse modo, pois do modo que ele pediu para definirmos da erro no compilador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está correto em sua suspeita. A palavra-chave `type` não deveria ter sido usada neste caso. O correto é `data`.

De forma resumida:

> Em Haskell, temos três maneiras básicas para declaração de tipos:
>
> - Usando `data` para novos tipos.
> - Usando `type` para declarar sinônimos de tipos, isto é, nomes alternativos para tipos já existentes.
> - Usando `newtype` para definir novos tipos equivalentes a outro existente.

Recomendo que leia mais sobre declaração de tipos, já que o sistema de tipos é parte fundamental de Haskell. Você pode começar pelo [Wikibook em português](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_tipos), de onde tirei essa referência.